# Is *&var redundant?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

New to C++ and trying to understand use of `*` and `&`.

I think I understand that `&*var` is useful if I want to have a reference variable to a pointer as a function argument, or just as a reference variable to a pointer in general. What about if the `&` and `*` are flipped?

Is `*&` redundant in C++?

Here's some code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    // example 1
    int num = 10;
    cout << *&num; // exact same as num?

    // example 2
    struct person
    {
        string name;
        int age;
    };

    person me[3];

    me[0].name = "my name";
    me[0].age = 321;

    cout << (*&me[0]).name << endl; // exact same as me[0].name?

    return 0;
}
```

1. Is the use of `*&var` in the two `cout`'s redundant because `&var` is an address and the `*` that comes before `&var` means to look at the variable the address is pointing to?
2. If it is not redundant, what is the use of `*&var` in C++?

Comment: Regarding _"`&*var` is useful if I want to have a reference variable to a pointer as a function argument"_, I think you are misunderstanding something. Reference types do not require special syntax when being initialized. It's unclear whether you wrote this code or acquired it from somewhere, but it is adding pointless syntax that makes it harder to read.

Comment: It seems redundant... but have you tried using it various ways and logging the address of each and their pointer value just to compare?  A pointer to an address does sound redundant.

Comment: You write a question about `*&` bein a part of *variable declaration*, and then proceed with code that has `*&` as a part of an *expression*. These are completely different usages of these characters.  `&` does not mean "reference" anywhere in this program.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In *most* cases, `*&var` (take the address of `var`, then dereference that address to access `var`) and `&*var` (dereference `var` to access the thing it points at, then take the address of that thing) are the same as just using `var` by itself.

However, a class type *can* overload `operator&` to return whatever address it wants, and overload `operator*` to return whatever reference it wants.  These are the only cases where `*&var` and `&*var` may not be the same as `var`. This is common in smart pointers and iterators, for instance.

To account for the former case, C++11 introduced [`std::addressof()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/addressof) to take the address of an object regardless of whether or not it overloads `operator&`, eg:

`*&var` -> `*std::addressof(var)`
`&*var` -> `std::addressof(*var)`

Comment: Since you mentioned overloading `&`, you can technically also overload `*`; why you'd want to, I've no idea though...

Comment: @fireshadow52 it is rare to overload `operator&` (some non-standard smart pointer classes do, like Microsoft's `CComPtr`), but most smart pointer classes, like `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr`, do overload `operator*`, to return a reference to the object they are pointing at. Same with iterators.

Comment: @fireshadow52 Overloading unary `operator*` happens all the time, for iterator and smart-pointer types. It's overloading unary `operator&` which is very rare and a code smell.

Comment: @RemyLebeau That's actually a good point; I was just thinking of cases where somebody might do something wacky and cause `*` to do something completely different.

Comment: @fireshadow52 the only time I've ever seen something like that is when people are inventing custom formulas that can be expressed directly in code expressions.  In practice, it is not a good idea to make `operator&` and `operator*` behave differently than they do for raw pointers.

Comment: With an array you can write `T *p = &arr[i];`. But say `arr` is a bitset or vector of bool then you have a problem. You can not address individual bits. So `arr[i]` needs to be a proxy object that stores both the address where the bit is located and which bit at that address is used. Now `&arr[i]` should give the address for the bit but would yield the address of the proxy object and that is probably not what you want. So you overload (or delete) `operator&`.

Comment: *"These are the only cases where [..] `&*var` may not be the same as `var`."*. `&*var` is not necessary valid, it requires "dereference-able" type (as pointer). `&*num` is wrong in OP's case (so not identical to valid `num`). :-)